# mongoose - set presentation of foreign key reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm developing an REST API for mobile app, This is part of model i'm using

```
var UserSchema = new Schema(
{
    email : 
    {
        type : String, 
        unique : true
    },
    login_type : String,
    username : 
    {
        type : String,
        index : true
    },
    password : String
}
```

And I added user's oid to post schema as reference

```
var PostSchema = new Schema(
{
    author : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "User"},
    board_id : {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : "Board"},
    regDate : Number,
    lastModDate : Number,
    title : String,
    content : String,
}
```

so, the posts can reference user collections to get `username` of user who posted it. So i want to get just username of user, others are not necessary.
For this, i used follows.

```
var query = Post.find({"regDate" :{$lte : before}},
{
    _id : 1,
    title : 1,
    "author.username" : 1,
    regDate : 1
})
```

but the mongoose ignored that `"author.username"`. How can i get just username of `author`, not all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `populate` function and enumerate selected fields there:

```
Post
    .find({ regDate :{ $lte : before }}, 'title reqDate')
    .populate('author', 'username')
    .exec();
```